# Pattern for serial-to-parallel-to-serial data processing

Tags: python

I'm working with arrays of datasets, iterating over each dataset to extract information, and using the extracted information to build a new dataset that I then pass to a parallel processing function that might do parallel I/O (requests) on the data.

The return is a new dataset array with new information, which I then have to consolidate with the previous one. The pattern ends up being Loop->parallel->Loop.

```
parallel_request = []
for item in dataset:
     transform(item)
     subdata = extract(item)
     parallel_request.append(subdata)

new_dataset = parallel_function(parallel_request)

for item in dataset:
    transform(item)
    subdata = extract(item)
    if subdata in new_dataset:
        item[subdata] = new_dataset[subdata]
```

I'm forced to use two loops. Once to build the parallel request, and the again to consolidate the parallel results with my old data. Large chunks of these loops end up repeating steps. This pattern is becoming uncomfortably prevalent and repetitive in my code.

Is there some technique to "yield" inside the first loop after adding data to `parallel_request`, continuing on to the next item. Once `parallel_request` is filled, execute `parallel function`, and then resume the loop for each item again, restoring the previously saved context (local variables).

EDIT: I think one solution would be to use a function instead of a loop, and call it recursively. The downside being that i would definitely hit the recursion limit.

```
parallel_requests = []
final_output = []
index = 0
def process_data(dataset, last=False):
    data = dataset[index]
    data2 = transform(data)
    data3 = expensive_slow_transform(data2)
    subdata = extract(data3)
    # ... some other work

    index += 1

    parallel_requests.append(subdata)

    # If not last, recurse
    # Otherwise, call the processing function.
    if not last:
        process_data(dataset, index == len(dataset))
    else:
        new_data = process_requests(parallel_requests)

    # Now processing of each item can resume, keeping it's
    # local data variables, transforms, subdata...etc.
    final_data = merge(subdata, new_data[index], data, data2, data3))
    final_output.append(final_data)

process_data(original_dataset)
```

Any solution would involve somehow preserving data, data2, data3, subdata...etc, which would have to be stored somewhere. Recursion uses the stack to store them, which will trigger the recursion limit. Another way would be store them in some array outside of the loop, which makes the code much more cumbersome. Another solution would be to just recompute them, and would also require code duplication.

So I suspect to achieve this you'd need some specific Python facility that enables this.

Comment: what do you imagine some pseudocode of what you are asking to look like? Im not clear on quite what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Just added some psudo code of what it could look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe i have solved the issue:

Based on the previous recursive code, you can can exploit the generator facilities offered by Python to preserve the serial context when calling the parallel function:

```
def process_data(dataset, parallel_requests, final_output):
    data = dataset[index]
    data2 = transform(data)
    data3 = expensive_slow_transform(data2)
    subdata = extract(data3)
    # ... some other work

    parallel_requests.append(subdata)

    yield

    # Now processing of each item can resume, keeping it's
    # local data variables, transforms, subdata...etc.
    final_data = merge(subdata, new_data[index], data, data2, data3))
    final_output.append(final_data)

final_output = []
parallel_requests = []
funcs = [process_data(datum, parallel_requests, final_output) for datum in dataset]
[next(f) for f in funcs]
process_requests(parallel_requests)
[next(f) for f in funcs]
```

The output list and generator calls are general enough that you can abstract away these lines in a helper function sets it up and calls the generators for you, leading to a very clean result with code overhead being one line for the function definition, and one line to call the helper.